# Sum of n prime numbers in Java

Tags: java

I have this problem, how can I make this code, work for the number of terms of the prime numbers and add them, currently, what it does is ask a cap, and from there add all the existing numbers that are, example
`5`, then I would summarize `2 + 3 + 5`, and I would have `10`, but I want to add `5` prime numbers, example `5`, then
`2, 3, 5, 7, 11 = 28`

I'm starting on this, thanks in advance:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int li, suma = 0;
int cont = 0;
System.out.println("Ingrese la longuitud de los numeros primos a sumar");
li = sc.nextInt();

for (int i = 2; i <= li; i++) {
    cont = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            cont++;
        }
    }
    if (cont == 2) {
        suma = suma + i;
    }
}
System.out.print(suma + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loop for `li` times, use a counter to count the number of prime numbers already added.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
int li, suma=0;
int cont = 0;
int counter = 0;
System.out.println("Ingrese la longuitud de los numeros primos a sumar");
li= sc.nextInt();

for(int i = 2; counter < li; i++)
{
    cont = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if(i % j == 0)
        {
            cont++;
        }
    }
    if(cont== 2 )
    {
        suma= suma + i;
        counter++;
    } 
}
System.out.print(suma + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have separate method to check if the number is prime and find the sum of primes to the count required as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int li, suma = 0;
    int cont = 0;  // track prime count
    System.out.println("Ingrese la longuitud de los numeros primos a sumar");
    li = sc.nextInt();
    int i = 2;  // start with 2 since least prime is 2
    while (li > cont) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= Math.sqrt(i); divisor++) {
            if (i % divisor == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break; 
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) { // if prime, add to sum and increase count
            suma += i;
            cont++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.print(suma + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should write a method check the number is prime or not.
After that, use loop statement to get first `count` prime. Then only sum that.
Hope it will help you

```
public static void  main (String args[]) {
    int count = 3;
    int sum = 0;
    int n = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (n == 2) {
            sum += n;
            n++;
        } else {
            while (!isPrime(n)) {
                n = n + 2;
            }
            sum += n;
            n = n + 2;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}

public static boolean isPrime(int i) {
    if (i == 2 || i == 3) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (i % 2 == 0) return false;
        for (int j = 3; j <= (i / 2) + 1; j = j + 2) {
            if (i % j == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need everything to be inside the first public, since the teacher has not yet taught us functions, nor booleans

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean calculate the sum of first `li` prime number?

```
int count = 0; // add a count to represent the number of prime number
for (int i = 2; i <= 100000000; i++) { // loop to a very large number
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            cont++;
        }
    }
    if (cont == 2) {
        suma = suma + i;
        count++;
        if (count == li) break; // break if the number of prime number is li
    }
}
```

Comment: how to make it start from 1? i mean, the sum of the numbers start in 2, i want include since the number 1

Comment: Didn't quite understand, but if you consider 1 as a prime then you can just add 1 to your final result.